# scala _.validate error message

Tags: scala, playframework

is there away in scala to print the correct error message why the validation does not work?

```
request.body.asJson.foreach(f = _.validate[ProcessSteps] match {
  case JsSuccess(processSteps, _) =>
  case _ => ?? error message?
```

That would be a big help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like JsSuccess you have a JsError that you can use capture errors. Below is an example -

```
request.body.asJson.foreach(f = _.validate[ProcessSteps] match {
    case JsSuccess(processSteps, _) =>
    case e: JsError => println("Errors: " + JsError.toJson(e).toString())
```

You can also use fold method like Form validation as shown below -

```
val nameOption: Option[String] = nameResult.fold(
  invalid = {
    fieldErrors => fieldErrors.foreach(x => {
      println("field: " + x._1 + ", errors: " + x._2)
    })
    None
  },
  valid = {
    name => Some(name)
  }
)
```

For more information have a look at [official documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJson#Using-validation)